# How to handle fail of $.when promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, deferred

I'm not understanding how `$.when` works during the fail when passing multiple AJAX calls. If one fails, does the fail callback trigger? Also, what is the parameter of the fail, one per ajax or is it one fail shared for all?

```
$.when(
    $.ajax('/url1'),
    $.ajax('/url2'))
   .done(function (resp1, resp2) {

    }).fail(function (??) {

    });
```

Comment: If one deferred fails, the wrapping $.when immediately fails as well.

Comment: Makes sense, but in the fail, how do I know which one failed? Is there one fail parameter per AJAX call or buried in the single fail parameter?

Comment: If one fails, the wrapping `$.when`'s fail is called right away, so the the arguments will be for the first `$.ajax` to fail as that's when the outer `fail()` will be called, makes sense ?

Comment: Exactly what Adeano says for the first failure. If you want to know about all failures, not just the first, then set `.fail()` handlers for each of the `$.ajax()` promises individually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be easy enough to check right?

```
var d1 = $.Deferred(), d2 = $.Deferred();

$.when(d1, d2)
   .fail(function (a, b) { 
      console.log(a, b); 
   });

d2.reject("hi!");
```

The output is `hi! undefined`. So only one argument gets passed.

http://jsfiddle.net/22b3L/

Comment: You really don't have to test it, it's pretty obvious that if the outer `fail()` attached to `$.when` is called immediately if one of the deferreds inside `$.when` is rejected, i.e. the ajax fails, the arguments will be passed from the failing ajax call only, as there is no guarantee that the other ajax calls will finish, and the outer `fail()` is called immediately, so there's no way to pass anything else.

Comment: `when(d1,d2).done(function (a, b) {})` does have two arguments though. A way to get around this is to require: `when_array([d1, d2]).done(spread(function (a, b) {}))`. In my experience with jQuery they have some very nice, but slightly arbitrary syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

`.then()` actually takes up to three arguments (success, fail, progress). You can either use `.fail()` as noted in other answers, or you can do something like:

```
$.when(async).then(function success(resp) {
        console.log('success');
    }, function fail(resp) {
        console.log('fail');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When any of the promises are rejected the final fail will be called.
If you'd like to do something different for each one, you could try something like this:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax('/url1').fail(function () { console.dir('fail 1'); }),
    $.ajax('/url2').fail(function () { console.dir('fail 2'); }))
.done(function (resp1, resp2) {

}).fail(function () {
    console.dir('fail any');
});
```

Fail any will be called immediately after one of the ajax requests failed, so other request-specific fails might be called afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I was working through something similar and thought it might be helpful to someone.

[A CodePen playground with $.when](http://codepen.io/logankd/pen/rOoKjq)

```
 var d1 = $.Deferred().fail(function(a){ console.log('on fail 1', a) }), 
    d2 = $.Deferred().fail(function(a){ console.log('on fail 2', a) }),
    d3 = $.Deferred().fail(function(a){ console.log('on fail 3', a) });
$.when(d1, d2, d3)
.then(function (a, b, c){
  console.log('then: ', a, b, c);
})
.fail(function (a, b, c) { 
  // only reports the first one that failed
  console.log('fail: ', a, b, c); 
})
.always(function(a, b, c){
  console.log('always: ', a, b, c);
});
d1.resolve("d1!");
d2.reject("d2!");
d3.reject("d3!");
```

[A way to 'recover' from 1 failed in the array of deferreds](http://codepen.io/logankd/pen/dYwjvW?editors=001)

```
'use strict';
var getConfigRequestDef = $.Deferred();
var getConfigDef = $.Deferred();
var getStatusRequestDef = $.Deferred();
var getStatusDef = $.Deferred();
getConfigRequestDef.then(function (cfg) {
    return getConfigDef.resolve(cfg);
}, function (c) {
    c.hasError = true;
    getConfigDef.resolve(c);
});
getStatusRequestDef.then(function (status) {
    return getStatusDef.resolve(status);
}, function (s) {
    s.hasError = true;
    getStatusDef.resolve(s);
});
var results = $.when(getConfigDef, getStatusDef).then(function (config, status) {
    console.log('The when\'s then: ', JSON.stringify(config), JSON.stringify(status));
});
var cfg = {
    id: 10,
    type: 'config',
    hasError: false
};
var statusObj = {
    id: 30,
    type: 'status',
    hasError: false
};
getConfigRequestDef.reject(cfg);
getStatusRequestDef.reject(statusObj);
```